# where can I find source code for system calls in linux?

Tags: linux-kernel

where can I find source code for read() system call in linux kernel? In the manual pages I can find the syntax of the system call but not the path to that particular system call.

Answer (score 1):

You can look in the [Linux kernel source code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux) on github or [LXR](http://lxr.linux.no/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are looking for: http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v4.10.1/fs/read_write.c#L584